# How to upload and move image in angular using laravel web API?

Tags: php, html, angular, laravel

student-api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentAPIService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  registerStudent(data){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost/angular_laravel/laravelAPI/addStudent', data, { headers: headers });
  }
}
```

add.component.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #fm="ngForm">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="registration">Student Registration</label><br/>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="fname">Full Name</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" ngModel>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label"  for="photo">Image</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" placeholder="" ngModel>
      </div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="registration(fm.value)">Register</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

add.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentAPIService } from 'src/app/services/student-api.service';
import { Student } from 'src/app/model/student';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.component.css']
})
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {

  public res: any;

  constructor( private studentAPI: StudentAPIService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  registration(fm){
    this.studentAPI.registerStudent(fm).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

}
```

Laravel Controller - StudentController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Student;
use DB;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
  public function store(Request $request) {

    if ($request->hasFile('photo'))
    {
        $file      = $request->file('photo');
        $filename  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $picture   = date('His').'-'.$filename;
        $file->move(public_path('img'), $picture);
        $student = new Student([
          'student_name' => $request->get('fname'),
          'photo' => $filename
        ]);
        $student->save();
        return response()->json('Successfully register');
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code I want to upload and move image using angular via laravel web API. Here, What happen when I click on button then try to print `dd($request->hasFile('photo'))` in `StudentController.php` then it return false. I don't know where I am doing wrong. Please help me.

Thank You